# Error using memcpy : "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000"

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy, function-definition

I am trying to write something similar to `std::vector` but in c to store a bunch of mathematical vectors.

Here is the line that is casing the error.

```
pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewData, pVl->pData, sizeof(pVl->pData));
```

My Intention: Copy data from `pVl->pData` to `pNewData`. Then assign the return value, which is the
pointer to start of the newly copied data memory and assign it to `pVl->pData`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

MRE:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum R_Code { R_OK, R_WARNING, R_FAIL, R_FATAL } R_Code;

struct Vector2_s
{
    float x;
    float y;
} const Default_Vector2 = { 0.0f, 0.0f };

typedef struct Vector2_s Vector2;

struct Vector2List_s
{
    //current capacity of the List
    size_t capacity;

    //current size of the list 
    size_t size;

    //data buffer 
    Vector2* pData;

} const Default_Vector2List = { 0, 0, NULL };

typedef struct Vector2List_s Vector2List;

R_Code Vector2List_ReAllocateMem(Vector2List* pVl) {
    if (pVl->capacity == 0) {
        pVl->capacity++;
    }

    Vector2* pNewData = malloc(pVl->capacity * 2 * sizeof(Vector2));
    if (pNewData == NULL) {
        return R_FAIL;
    }

    pVl->capacity *= 2;
    pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewData, pVl->pData, sizeof(pVl->pData));//EXPECTION THROWN IN THIS LINE
    free(pNewData);
    return R_OK;
}

R_Code Vector2List_PushBack(Vector2List* pVl, const Vector2 v) {
    if (pVl->size == pVl->capacity) {
        R_Code rcode = Vector2List_ReAllocateMem(pVl);
        if (rcode == R_FAIL) {
            return rcode;
        }
    }

    pVl->pData[pVl->size] = v; 
    pVl->size++;
    return R_OK;
}

int main() {

    Vector2List vl = Default_Vector2List;
    Vector2List_PushBack(&vl, Default_Vector2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, its the first one

Comment: Seems that allocation failed. Check the allocated size.

Comment: `pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewData, pVl->pData, sizeof(pVl->pData));` You don't need to reassign, also your `sizeof` operand is wromg.

Comment: The message tells you that you read from a `NULL` pointer. Either `pv` or `pv->data` is `NULL`.

Comment: This will not work: `pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewData, pVl->pData, sizeof(pVl->pData)); free(pNewData);`. `memcpy` returns the value of `dest`, i.e. in your case `pNewData`. You mustn't free it if you want to use it later via `pVl->pData`. Also it will only copy 4 or 8 bytes depending on the size of a pointer in your system. It will not copy the whole memory. Finally you don't have access to the old value of `pData` and cannot free it afterwards.

Comment: Just after the memcpy, you're free-ing pNewData right after you copied to it.   I don't understand the logic.

Comment: @Gerhardh I thought  `pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewDat...` would have the same affect as `pVl->pData = pNewData;` as suggest by the answer below.

Comment: Yes, it does. But in the next line you put that address into `free`, i.e. the newly allocated memory. Both variables contain the same address after this line but the block is only allocated once. If you free that block via one pointer, all other pointers pointing to the same address musn't be dereferenced any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the function `Vector2List_ReAllocateMem` you allocated dynamically memory

```
Vector2* pNewData = malloc(pVl->capacity * 2 * sizeof(Vector2));
```

then in this statement

```
pVl->pData = memcpy(pNewData, pVl->pData, sizeof(pVl->pData));
```

you are using the null pointer `pVl->pData` as a source of data that invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover you freed the allocated memory.

```
free(pNewData);
```

Also using this expression `sizeof(pVl->pData)` does not make a sense.

It seems what you need is the following

```
pVl->pData = pNewData;
```

Though if you are going to reallocate memory then instead of `malloc` you need to use `realloc`.

You need to rewrite the function entirely.

Comment: What should I use instead of `sizeof(pVl->pData)`? Or what is the size of `pV1->pData`?

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes it is your job to keep track about the size that was allocated for `pVl->pData` earlier. You cannot retrieve it from the pointer alone.

Comment: @Gerhardh Wait I do  have a size variable. Would I use that instead? if size is the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes You don't need the number of elements but the number of bytes. If you can get this from your `size` like e.g. `pVl->capacity * 2 * <xy>` then go with it. BTW: Do you know `realloc`? Might be a better fit for you.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes The pointer is declared like Vector2* pData;. So you need to allocate objects of the type Vector2. So use sizeof( Vector2  )